# Como guardar valores de de metodos en coleccion(es)?

Tags: java, netbeans

en mi intento de hacer codigos mas limpios, quiero aprender a trabajar con metodos, pero no pillo como guardar los valores de estos cuando son llamados en otra clase

Algunos de los metodos que hice son:

*Nota: No se si estan correctos o es la forma adecuada de hacerlo, solo los hice siguiendo mi logica de lo poco y nada que sé*

```
public void ObtenerNombre() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fakeNombre;
    System.out.println("Ingrese un N O M B R E");
    fakeNombre = sc.next();
    if (fakeNombre.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No puede dejar el campo vacio");
    } else {
        if (fakeNombre.matches("[A-Za-z]")) {
            System.out.println("Genial \n El nombre " + fakeNombre + "se a guardado");
            Nombre = fakeNombre;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Solo se admiten letras");
        }
    }
}

public void ObtenerApellidos(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese Apellido Paterno");
    String fakeAP = sc.next();
    if(fakeAP.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No puede dejar el campo vacio");
    }
    else{
        if (fakeAP.matches("[A-Za-z]")){
            System.out.println("Ingrese Apellido Materno");
            String fakeAM = sc.next();
            if(fakeAM.matches("[A-Za-z]")){
                System.out.println("Genial \n los apellidos " + fakeAP + fakeAM + "se han guardado");
                Apellido = fakeAP + fakeAM;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Solo se admiten letras");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Solo se admiten letras");
        }
    }
}
public void EdadPasajero(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fakeEdad;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la E D A D del pasajero");
    fakeEdad = sc.nextInt();

    if(fakeEdad > 0){
        System.out.println("Edad Correcta");
        pEdad = fakeEdad;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("E D A D no valida");
    }
}
```

El problema es que no sé como guardar esos valores dentro de una coleccion, especificamente un HashMap

```
public void addPasajero(){
    Pasajero nPasajero = new Pasajero();
    nPasajero.ObtenerNombre();
    nPasajero.ObtenerApellidos();
    nPasajero.EdadPasajero();
    nPasajero.EdadPasajero();

    agregarPasajero(Rut, new Pasajero(Pasaje, pEdad, Nombre, Apellido, Rut), Pasajeros);
}
public void agregarPasajero(String Rut, Pasajero Pasajero, HashMap<String, Pasajero> Pasajeros) {

    if (Pasajeros.containsKey(Rut)) {
        System.out.println("No es posible agregar este R U T. El código esta repetido.");
    } else {
        Pasajeros.put(Rut, Pasajero);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @iFabio, los métodos que has puesto al principio, ¿Están dentro de la clase pasajero? ¿y los que has puesto al final?

Comment: @David DPG los metodos ObtenerNombre  ObtenerApellido están en la clase Persona,  EdadPasajero está en la clase Pasajero (extends persona) addPasajero/agregarPasajero estan en una clase llamada Vuelo, que es un paquete distinto(ya importe el paquete que contiene Persona y Pasajero)